# ¿Cómo separo texto por guiones bajos (_) de una celda en una hoja de cálculo de google con expresiones regulares (regex)?

Tags: regex, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy intentando extraer ítems de una cadena separada por `_` para Google Data Studio. Pero como tiene la misma fórmula que Google Sheets, hago la pregunta para una hoja de cálculo, sabiendo que únicamente puedo resolverlo con una expresión regular (y no con [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) por ejemplo)

Necesito crear varias columnas desde una cadena de texto con la siguiente estructura:

```
CampañaA_caracteristica1_caracteristica2_caracteristica3_3214534
```

**Pregunta:** ¿Cómo puedo extraer cada campo en una columna diferente, excepto por el número final y los guiones bajos?

En todos los campos puede haber cualquier cantidad de caracteres, mayúsculas o minúsculas y números. El único campo que contiene sólo números es el último.

Es decir, el resultado debería ser el siguiente (cada campo en una columna separada)

```
CampañaA
caracteristica1
caracteristica2
caracteristica3
```

Tiene que ser **sí o sí con RegEx**, no con otra fórmula ni con separar columnas.

**Qué intenté:** Hasta ahora puede hacer esto: `[a-zA-Z]+` pero selecciona todo excepto los `"_"`.

¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar lo que intentaste hasta ahora, por más que no funcione? Además, ¿por qué no podrías usar `=SPLIT()`?

Comment: hasta ahora puede hacer esto: `[a-zA-Z]+` pero selecciona todo excepto los "_". No se como hacer para elegir cada uno de los slots. Tengo que usar las funciones de regex de google spreadsheets si o si, porque es para usar en Google data studio, que admite las mismas de las spreadsheets.

Comment: ¿La expresión regular es para Google Data Studio o para las hojas de cálculo de Google?

Comment: en realidad es para Google Data Studio. Pero tienen la misma lógica que las hojas de calculo.

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a la misma sintáxis. Señalo esto porque dentro de "la lógica" de la hoja de cálculo está la práctica de usar usar funciones como ARRAYFORMULA y COLUMN las cuales no están disponibles en [tag:google-data-studio].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aclaremos: esto normalmente se haría con [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136), que popula automáticamente hacia la derecha.

[image: =SPLIT($A1;"_")]

O, para todas las filas: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT($A1:A;"_")))`

[image: =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT($A1:A;"_")))]

<sup>* Gracias a [Rubén](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/65/rub%C3%A9n) por [el comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55362/c%C3%B3mo-separo-texto-por-guiones-bajos-de-una-celda-en-una-hoja-de-c%C3%A1lculo-de/55378#comment99019_55378) recomendando usar esto.</sup>

O, usando expresiones regulares, podríamos repetir el grupo `([^_]*)_` tantas veces como `"_"` haya en el campo:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
    REGEXEXTRACT(
        $A1:A;
        REPT("([^_]*)_";LEN($A1:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1:A;"_";"")))
    )))
```

[image: =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT($A1:A;REPT("([^_]*)_";LEN($A1:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1:A;"_";""))))))]

Con una sola fórmula en una sola celda, rellenamos toda la hoja.

Pero veamos esto sólo con expresiones regulares, una para cada ítem, y sin usar otras fórmulas, para luego poder usarlo en Google Data Studio.

---

### Consumir y capturar

Imaginémonos que estamos en la 3er columna, y que queremos obtener la tercer subcadena. En ese caso, deberíamos hacer que la expresión regular consuma los primeros 2 items, y que capture el 3ro.

Bien [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) devuelve únicamente el texto capturado por un grupo (la parte del patrón que esté entre paréntesis). Entonces el objetivo será: que coincida con los 2 primeros items, y que coincida con el 3ro entre paréntesis.

Para que coincida con los 2 primeros:

```
^(?:[^_]*_){2}
```

- `^` - Coincide con el inicio del texto (evita que haya una coincidencia desde el medio del texto)
- `(?:`..`){2}` - Es un grupo, que repite el patrón contenido 2 veces. Cada vez:

  - `[^_]*` - Cualquier caracter excepto `"_"`, repetido entre 0 o más veces.
  - `_` - Una `"_"`.

Se puede considerar como *un loop repetido 2 veces que en cada iteración coincide con el texto entre separadores, y el separador posterior*.

Y, por último, **capturamos** el último ítem:

```
^(?:[^_]*_){2}([^_]*)_
              ^^^^^^^^
```

- `(`..`)` - Es el grupo que usamos para capturar:

  - `[^_]*` - Cualquier texto que no sea `"_"`.
- `_` - Seguido de la `"_"` posterior.

---

### Fórmula

Ahora, sólo tenemos que cambiar el **`{2}`** por el número de la columna en la que estemos, y para eso usamos [COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373).

Si el texto está en `A1`, y queremos obtener los ítems en `B1`, `C1`, etc; entonces calculamos cuántos ítems se deben consumir con:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT($A1;"^(?:[^_]*_){" & (COLUMN() - COLUMN($A1) - 1) & "}([^_]*)_")
```

Y luego se puede copiar esta fórmula en todas las celdas que quieras. En la hoja, quedaría así:

[image: captura de la hoja]

> Para separar los parámetros se usa `;`, `,` (u otro) dependiendo de la configuración regional.

**Evitar errores cuando no hay más ítems**

Para que no muestre `#N/A` cuando no quedan ítems, usamos [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304).

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT($A1;"^(?:[^_]*_){" & (COLUMN() - COLUMN($A1) - 1) & "}([^_]*)_"))
```

**Completar para todas las filas**

Volvemos a usar [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) para que Google Sheet complete automáticamente todas las filas, usando como ingreso el rango `$A1:$A`.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
    REGEXEXTRACT($A1:$A;"^(?:[^_]*_){" & (COLUMN() - COLUMN($A1) - 1) & "}([^_]*)_")
 ))
```

[image: =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT($A1:$A;"^(?:[^_]*_){" & (COLUMN() - COLUMN($A1) - 1) & "}([^_]*)_")))]

**Completar columnas**

Lo que hice fue pegar esta misma fórmula en las celdas `C1`, `D1`, etc. hasta el máximo que quiero de ítems. Intenté hacerlo también con ARRAYFORMULA pero no pude, quizás otro pueda solucionarlo.

---

### Llevar a Google Data Studio

Data Studio permite ingresar como fuente de datos a una hoja de Google Sheet.

[image: Nueva fuente de datos - Hoja de Google Hojas de Cálculo]

Sin embargo, si el origen fuese otro, podrías generar nuevas *dimensiones*:

- Item 1: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Columna de base de datos, '^([^_]*)_')`
- Item 2: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Columna de base de datos, '^(?:[^_]*_){1}([^_]*)_')`
- Item 3: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Columna de base de datos, '^(?:[^_]*_){2}([^_]*)_')`
- Item 4: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Columna de base de datos, '^(?:[^_]*_){3}([^_]*)_')`
- etc.

[image: Agregar dimensión]

Y mostrarlo en el informe, por ejemplo en una tabla (o donde quieras):

[image: Tabla final en el informe]

- Cabe aclarar que, además de las *dimensiones*, la tabla debe tener al menos 1 *métrica*.

Comment: Se puede usar ARRAFORMULA para con una única fórmula obtener el mismo resultado que con varias :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200697/trying-to-split-within-arrayformula-inside-google-spreadsheet/30202802#30202802

Comment: Habrá que mencionar que 1. fórmula y función son dos conceptos distintos y 2. no todas las funciones están en ambas aplicaciones.

Comment: @Mariano Muchas gracias, funciono excelente en data studio!!!